# Haskell: Get block for Sudoku solver

Tags: haskell

I am trying to build a Sudoku solver for a project I am working on. I have a 9x9 grid with each position numbered 0..80, left to right, top to bottom

e.g.:

0  1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8

9  10 ...

I am trying to return a list of Int's that represent the 3x3 grid that a position falls in. For example for position 1, which is in grid (0,0) it would return [0,1,2,9,10,11,18,19,20] and for position 8, which is in grid (0,2) it would return [6,7,8,15,16,17,24,25,26].

I have written a function which returns the required 3x3 grid, on a 9x9 Sudoku:

```
getBlock :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
getBlock x y = [[((x * sudokuSizeSq + 0) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 0),((x * sudokuSizeSq + 0) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 1)..((x * sudokuSizeSq + 0) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1))],[((x * sudokuSizeSq + 1) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 0),((x * sudokuSizeSq + 1) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 1)..((x * sudokuSizeSq + 1) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1))],[((x * sudokuSizeSq + 2) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 0),((x * sudokuSizeSq + 2) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 1)..((x * sudokuSizeSq + 2) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1))]]
```

Where: 
sudokuSizeSq is the square of the width (3)
sudokuSize is the width (9)

x and y represent the possible grids.

This works, however I would like to increase it so it will work for larger grids. I changed my code to the follow but it seems then wont load the function.

```
getBlock :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
getBlock x y = [[((x * sudokuSizeSq + 0) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 0),((x * sudokuSizeSq + 0) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 1)..((x * sudokuSizeSq + 0) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1))],[((x * sudokuSizeSq + 1) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 0),((x * sudokuSizeSq + 1) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 1)..((x * sudokuSizeSq + 1) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1))]..[((x * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1)) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 0),((x * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1)) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + 1)..((x * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1)) * sudokuSize) + (y * sudokuSizeSq + (sudokuSizeSq-1))]]
```

The way I'm doing it seems very cumbersome, is there a better way to do this or a way to fix the problem I'm having. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ a + b
| a <- take sudokuSizeSq $ map (sudokuSize *) [x * sudokuSizeSq .. ]
, b <- take sudokuSizeSq [y * sudokuSizeSq ..] ]
```

Comment: This nearly gives the correct results. however is i do x as 1 and y as 0, it returns [9,10,11,18,19,20,27,28,29], where as it should return [27,28,29,36,37,38,45,46,47]

Comment: @Joseph: Yeah, typo on my part.  Nearly?  Curious as to which part is off.

Comment: Sorry - pressed enter and it submitted my comment before I finished it - i have edited it above.

Comment: @Joseph: Ah, it's just not skipping far enough.  Well, that's easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Nearly there but not quite. The first line is now always correct, but the next two lines should then be the ones exactly below. For example currently x as 1 y as 1 returns [30,31,32,57,58,59,84,85,86] where as it should return [30,31,32,39,40,41,48,49,50]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. If you have a chance, could you brielfy explain exactly what it is doing, I'm especially not sure what the take sudokuSizeSq bit does. No worries if you don't have time though.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk over the x/y offsets in each block to generate all the positions in it. List comprehensions make this rather easy:

```
getBlock :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
getBlock x y = [[(y*sudokuSizeSq+dy)*sudokuSize + x*sudokuSizeSq+dx | dx <- offsets]
                | dy <- offsets]
    where offsets = [0..sudokuSizeSq-1]
```