# Find 9 3x3 "blocks" of Sudoku board (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, sudoku

I am learning Haskell and I decided to embark on a small sudoku solver as a project. I have been using [this assignment](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2014/course/TDA555/lab3.html) as a guide and I recently hit a wall on sub-problem `D2` which is to create a function that will generate the sudoku blocks (9 3x3 grids) from a Sudoku board (a 9x9 grid).

I started writing the following code but I quickly realized it was a terrible idea. It is clunky code that is not idiomatic Haskell (in my opinion) and completely violates the DRY principle.

```
type Block = [Maybe Int]
data Sudoku = Sudoku [[Maybe Int]]

blocks :: Sudoku -> [Block]
blocks (Sudoku rs) = block1 : block2 : block3 : block4 : block5 : block6 : block7 : block8 : block9 : []
  where block1 = [(rs!!0)!!0] ++ [(rs!!0)!!1] ++ [(rs!!0)!!2] ++ [(rs!!1)!!0] ++ [(rs!!1)!!1] ++ [(rs!!1)!!2]++ [(rs!!2)!!0] ++ [(rs!!2)!!1] ++ [(rs!!2)!!2]  
        block2 = ...
        block3 = ...
        ...
```

**I was wondering how to write a more concise and idiomatic function to complete the task?** How would you implement it? Any ideas are appreciated!

I have also consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270501/how-to-create-lists-of-3x3-sudoku-block-in-python) previous and possibly related SO question but I was not sure how to convert the pythonic solution to Haskell and whether or not I even should. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851802/haskell-get-block-for-sudoku-solver) question but I have structured my Sudoku board differently.

All of my current code can be found [here](https://github.com/2016rshah/sudoku-solver/blob/master/src/Main.hs). Also, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write a `groupBy3` function which groups a list by three elements:

```
groupBy3 :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

Then use the following chain of operations:

- `map groupBy3`
- `transpose`
- `concat`
- `groupBy3`
- `map concat`

Written on my phone, so it's untested but it should be close.

Update: I verified that this works:

```
groupBy3 (a:b:c:ds) = [a,b,c] : groupBy3 ds
groupBy3 []         = []
groupBy3 as         = [ as ]  -- won't happen

boxes =  map concat . groupBy3 . concat . transpose . map groupBy3

grid = [ [ [i,j] | j <- ['1'..'9'] ] | i <- ['a'..'i'] ]

test1 = boxes grid
```

Comment: Okay great, the code works but would it be possible for you to please add a bit of explanation for your solution?

Comment: Just trace out the execution - first look at `map groupBy3 boxes`, then `transpose $ map groupBy3 boxes`, then `concat $ transpose $ map groupBy3 boxes`, etc. and you'll see how it works. And if you found this answer helpful, an upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to add an edit with type signatures and the code I actually used and all if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, although perhaps not as elegant as the accepted answer:

```
map concat [(map  (take 3 . drop i) . (take 3 . drop j)) grid | i <- [0, 3, 6], j <- [0, 3, 6]]
```

where `grid` is the 9x9 Sudoku grid.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer for this problem but you're much better off using arrays rather than lists. Since you need to change elements, you'll probably want to use [mutable arrays](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/array/Data-Array-ST.html).

You could then implement blocks as "views" of the base array, simply by applying different offsets to the index operations, there is no need to copy them.

Comment: Sudoku solvers are one of the problem domains where `Data.Map` usually offers better performance than mutable arrays (because some sudoku puzzles can't be solved without trial and error, and in general the simpler a solver is the more trial and error it will use on a given puzzle)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:
boxsize = 3 is for (9 x 9) grid, for (4 X 4) grid you can use boxsize = 2

```hs
boxsize :: Int
boxsize = 3

boxes :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
boxes [] = []
boxes xss = takeBox (take boxsize xss) ++ boxes (drop boxsize xss)
            where 
                takeBox ([]:_) = []
                takeBox yss = concatMap (take boxsize) yss : takeBox (map (drop boxsize) yss)
```